# Match patterns in files and cut/delete lines in between

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

I have a text (input.txt) file containing the following pattern:

```
#########
##### AV1 
#########
great picture
good tv
decent sound
vibrant color
#########
#########
#### AV2 new TV
#########
we are testing this out now
this is 4K
need HDMI
#########
#########
### AV3 not working
#########
not enough ports
buy new device
#########
```

What I am in need for is the following output of 3 seperate files:

File 1.txt

```
#########
##### AV1 
#########
great picture
good tv
decent sound
vibrant color
#########
```

File 2.txt

```
#########
#### AV2 new TV
#########
we are testing this out now
this is 4K
need HDMI
#########
```

File 3.txt

```
#########
### AV3 not working
#########
not enough ports
buy new device
#########
```

I am not sure how to search and match patterns in 3 consecutive lines and then ignore the texts in between and find the #### at the end. Then I need to take the texts in between and output a new file.

I am able to "greedily" match the first 3 lines with the following regex:

```
/^#*\_^#*\_^#.*$
```

Comment: so the `*first 3 lines*` is simply a match of 3 consecutive lines starting with a `#`? how do you determine the output file numbering ... first match gets `1`, or is it derived from a number in the 2nd line (`AV1`, `AV2`, `AV3` in this case)?

Comment: please update the questino with the complete commands (`sed`? `awk`? something else?) you've tried with your regex; also include the (wrong) output generated by each of your code attempts

Comment: @markp-fuso:
Number of files corresponds to AV1, AV2, AV3

Comment: please update the question with the additional details re: how to number the files; also, is each 'chunk' of lines *guaranteed* to have a line that starts with `### AV<number>`?

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk '
/^#{7,}/ {
   ++n
   if (n%3 == 1) {
      close(fn)
      fn = "file" (++c) ".txt"
   }
}
{
   print > fn
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

When your requirement may be formulated as "split after the first line of each pair of lines with 9 hashes", you can use

```
csplit -b "%d"  --suppress-matched -f "File " \
  <(sed -rz 's/(#{9})\n\1/\1\n\n\1/g' input.txt) /^$/ '{*}'
```

Explanation:
`-b "%d"`: Get filenumbers without leading 0
`--suppress-matched`: Skip the empty lines that will be inserted
`-f "File "`: basename of the files created
`<(...)`: use output of the command like it is a file
`sed -rz 's/(#{9})\n\1/\1\n\n\1/g' input.txt`: create an empty line between 2 patterns  with 9 times `#`
`/^$/`: Empty line
`'{*}'`: Repeat csplit pattern for the complete file

Comment: If the files must start with 1, insert a newline at the beginning of the file and remove the `0` file after the csplit. Also perhaps append `.txt` to the  `-b` option, BTW `--suppress-matched` can be truncated to `--sup`.